# Convert byte array to string of bytes

Tags: c#

```
byte[] val = { 3, 4, 5 };

Dictionary<String, Object> dict = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
dict.Add("val", val);
//...

string request_json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
Console.Out.WriteLine(request_json);
```

This produces

```
{"val":[3,4,5]}
```

What's the best way to convert `val` such that the above produces the following (or equivalent) instead:

```
{"val":"\u0003\u0004\u0005"}
```

(This is passed to a web service which expects a string of arbitrary bytes rather than an array of arbitrary bytes.)

---

In case it helps, I would have used the following in Perl:

```
pack "C*", @bytes
```

A more descriptive Perl solution would be:

```
join "", map { chr($_) } @bytes
```

Comment: This should do the trick: `var b = String.Join("", val.Select(_ => @"\u"+_.ToString("X4")));`

Comment: var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArraVar); -> this will do the job, too bad the question is closed ;)

Comment: @Quantic, That's not the meaning it would have. Picture `val` containing the a `.zip` file, for example.

Comment: @mybirthname, That encodes according to the ANSI code page. That's no good.

Comment: But that does not print the `\u` which i thought was needed.

Comment: and won't work for numbers like 3,4. try to run it with `val = {3,4, 5, 6, 7,  65, 66};`

Comment: OIC, it's the json doing that - got it

Comment: sure - posted just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
dict.Add("val", String.Join("", val.Select(_ => (char)_)));
```

or as suggested by Michael:

```
dict.Add("val", String.Concat(val.Select(_ => (char)_)));
```

Comment: I think you can use String.Concat instead of String.Join with an empty delimiter.

Comment: What does `_` mean in C# lamba?

Comment: @LeiYang it has no special meaning, it is just a valid variable name. the `_` could just have been as easily called `x` or `value`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(val.Length);
foreach (byte b in val) {
    sb.Append((char)b);
}

dict.Add("val", sb.ToString());
```

Note: `Convert.ToChar(b)` could be used instead of `(char)b`.